# Blog has an infinite redirect loop

Tags: redirect, blog, nginx

Why is http://compassionpit.com/blog/ going through an infinite redirect loop? Here's my nginx conf file. The site is run by a nodejs server on port 8000 and Apache serves up the blog (wordpress) and the forum (phpBB). The forum is resolving just fine, at http://www.compassionpit.com/forum/ ...

> This webpage has a redirect loop The webpage at
>   http://www.compassionpit.com/blog/ has resulted in too many redirects.
>   Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies
>   may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration
>   issue and not a problem with your computer.

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     www.compassionpit.org;
    rewrite         ^/(.*) http://www.compassionpit.com/$1  permanent;
}


server {
    listen       80;                # your server's public IP address
    server_name  www.compassionpit.com;
    index        index.php index.html;

    location ~ ^/$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location @blogphp {
        internal;
        root /opt/blog/;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ ^/(forum|blog)/($|.*\.php) {
        root /opt/;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ ^/(forum|blog) {
        root /opt/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @blogphp;
    }

    location ~ ^/(forum|blog)/ {
       root /opt/;
    }


    location @backend {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ / {
        root /opt/chat/static/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is WordPress configured to use www or without www?  Your server seems to be listening only for the `www` version and tries to redirect non-`www` requests to the `www` version.

Considering that you provided a link to the non-`www` version of the domain above, my guess is that WordPress is trying to hook on to `http://compassionpit.com`, but your server redirects those requests to `http://www.compassionpit.com` and WordPress redirects it back to `http://compassionpit.com`.

If that is indeed what's going on, either kill the `www` redirect on your server or tell WordPress (by setting your options directly through phpMyAdmin) to use the `www` version of the domain.

Comment: Excellent, that sounds exactly like what I should do!  What setting in the SQL should I edit?  I'm comfortable with going in directly to MySQL, I just have no idea what table to look at and what entry/field to adjust... :)

Comment: Take a look at siteurl and blog_url in the settings table (wp_options).  The [Codex is a good reference as well](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database).

Comment: Very very helpful.  Thank you so much. I had to change the 'home' option_value and the 'siteurl' option_value.

Comment: I had a very similar problem where it redirected 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1:80

Answer (score 0):

Also check ownership/permissions.  If WordPress can't do it's job, something like this will fail over and over again:

`if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^.+/?(/wp-.*) $1 last;
                rewrite ^.+/?(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
                rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I solved it by adding the following to theme's functions.php

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```